# XSLT dynamic Sum based on a parameter

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing, apache-camel, xslt-2.0

I am calling this XSL from Apache Camel and I set the header of the message to the parameter, but still I don't get the result.

I want an XSLT which gives me the sum based on a parameter the problem is that the parameter could be multiple values or one value

```
<EmpJob>
<EmpJob>
<userId>testID</userId>
<EmpPayCompRecurring>
            <payComponent>1010</payComponent>
            <endDate>2020-06-30T00:00:00.000</endDate>
            <paycompvalue>3025.67</paycompvalue>
            <userId>testID</userId>
            <currencyCode>EUR</currencyCode>
            <startDate>2020-06-01T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmpPayCompRecurring>
 <EmpPayCompRecurring>
            <payComponent>6097</payComponent>
            <endDate>2019-12-31T00:00:00.000</endDate>
            <paycompvalue>100.0</paycompvalue>
            <userId>testID</userId>
            <currencyCode>EUR</currencyCode>
            <startDate>2018-12-06T00:00:00.000</startDate>
        </EmpPayCompRecurring>
</EmpJob>
</EmpJob>
```

I created an XSLT transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name = "custReturnDate" />
    <xsl:template match="/EmpJob">
        
         <xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="payrecur">'1010','6097' </xsl:variable>

     <mainroot>
     <xsl:for-each select="EmpJob">
            <root>
                    <__metadata>
                      
                        <uri><xsl:value-of select="concat('EmpCompensation(seqNumber=1L,startDate=datetime',$apos ,$custReturnDate, $apos,',userId=',$apos,userId,$apos,')')"/></uri>
                    </__metadata>
                  
                    <customDouble13><xsl:value-of select="sum(EmpPayCompRecurring[$payrecur]/paycompvalue) "/></customDouble13>

                </root>
           
     
        </xsl:for-each>
    </mainroot>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

"payrecur" should be the parameter later on according to this parameter I should sum node values.

P.S. I can change the parameter to anything because I am calling the template from code.

Comment: Can you add your camel route here too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given XSLT 2 or 3, I would declare the parameter as a sequence of strings or integers and then compare `sum(EmpPayCompRecurring[payComponent = $payrecur]/paycompvalue)`.

So declare e.g `<xsl:param name="payrecur" as="xs:string*" select="'1010','6097'"/>`.

A minimal stylesheet would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:param name = "custReturnDate" />
    
    <xsl:param name="payrecur" as="xs:string*" select="'1010','6097'"/>
    
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/EmpJob">
        
         <xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>

     <mainroot>
     <xsl:for-each select="EmpJob">
            <root>
                    <__metadata>
                      
                        <uri><xsl:value-of select="concat('EmpCompensation(seqNumber=1L,startDate=datetime',$apos ,$custReturnDate, $apos,',userId=',$apos,userId,$apos,')')"/></uri>
                    </__metadata>
                  
                    <customDouble13>
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum(EmpPayCompRecurring[payComponent = $payrecur]/paycompvalue)"/>
                        </customDouble13>

                </root>
           
     
        </xsl:for-each>
    </mainroot>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

At https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzkTcM I get `<customDouble13>3125.67</customDouble13>`. You will probably want to add `exclude-result-prefixes="#all"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I did as you mentioned but i am getting an exception "net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException" could you please test from your side Thanks

Comment: Which version of Saxon do you run? How do you run it, from the command line or with Java code? Can you edit your question and show the details there? You need to declare the prefix `xs` as `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` in your stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks I added the prefix now i am not getting any exception I am calling it from Apache Camel I send in the parameter "'1010','6097'" but i am getting zero values. I even displayed it again to make sure that it is comming correctly and indeed it is coming like this

Comment: @Ibrahim, I have edited the answer with a more complete sample and the result I get for the sum when running with Saxon 9.8 HE. I don't know about Camel and how you set parameters there, you might want to add a tag for Camel if the problem occurs in that context.

Comment: Thanks it is indeed working but using the Camel it is not I added also a tag for Camel thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe if you can tell me how to convert string seperated with "," to string sequence would be great

Comment: In case anyone would need to use this you can use tokenize(
   'a, b, c', '[,\s]+')

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone in case anyone faces this type of scenario as I mentiond before I added the parameter in the header so that the XSLT template will get it. Unfortunatly the template received it as a String so I had to use the function tokenize() to convert the parameter to array then I could use the template provided by Martin Honnen.

This scenario will work Apache Camel as well as SAP CPI

Best Regards
Ibrahim